# Can't run > npm run watch on Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I have installed NodeJS v10.9.0 NodeJS version & NPM 6.2.0. I try to developing Laravel with VueJS from Laravel fresh installation. I installed below devDependencies inside **package.json** :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

After installation, I got some messages like this :

> notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

And this :

> added 333 packages from 293 contributors and audited 26962 packages in
>   117.917s found 27 vulnerabilities (19 low, 7 moderate, 1 high)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

And then I try to `npm run watch` but failed, and shows this message :

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\0Projects\Laravel\larastore\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js'

And then I check the node_modules and try to find the specific file, but it's none. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Mix and other packages are not installed. use **npm install laravel-mix** .

Check package.json and will be able to find which other modules you need. 
You might also need package like **cross-env** .